# Azure Web App deployment slot load testing

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

Would it make sense to do performance (load) tests on a test deployment slot and then swap it to production and expect the same performance after the swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment slots run on the same underlying resource. That means if you do the load testing you will impact the performance of you production slot.

However if it is a new deployment then you should be fine doing this since the performance should be identical between slots as long as the underlying code and config make it act the same.

Comment: Does it mean that deployment and production instances share cpu/memory? Let's I have 2gb memory app plan. With 5 deployment slots their total memory usage will be limited to 2gb?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

All deployment slots are created on the same machine. So yes, in that you are testing the same slot on the same machine.

On the other hand, a load test in a shared environment is never 100% reliable as it's possible that something else in the environment might interfere with it.

Also keep in mind though that if you hammer it, it will also affect the current production slot, because they are both on the same machine.